# How can I manually indent (format) my monaco-editor's code?

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm having some problems in formatting my code as soon as it is imported to the editor.

I tried

```
editor.getAction('editor.action.formatDocument').run();
```

but `getAction` only returns `null`.

My editor was typed as `monaco.editor.ICommonEditor`.

Never had much experience with `monaco-editor`, so I might be doing something wrong.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use this, assuming your variable for the Monaco editor is editor.

```js
editor.trigger("anyString", 'editor.action.formatDocument');
```

It has been discussed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/32)

Answer (score 0):

Which language you are using in monaco-editor ?
For JSON, what i did before setting content to editor, I used JSON.stringify method to format the content properly.